# A circle is given, find E

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm stuck with this problem:

> A circle is given: $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$, find $E(x^2|y)$

I thought of using symmetry (turn it into $E(y^2|y)$, and as $E(y|y) = 0$, then the answer is $0$), but it did not work.

Thanks!

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What is the joint distribution of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: @xzm it is not stated in this task

Comment: $E[y|y]$ would be $y$, not zero.

Comment: I think you can use uniform distribution on the circle because otherwise this problem lacks enough info

Comment: $E(x^2 \mid y)$ is not symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

I am far from being an expert on probability theory. I read [Wikipedia's this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation). I am trying to give an answer.

There is a uniform distribution on the disk with joint density function $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{\pi}.$ Therefore,
$$E(x^2|y)=\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}x^2\frac{dx}{\pi}=\frac{2(1-y^2)^{3/2}}{3\pi}.$$

My reasoning (checking):

1. $\int_{-1}^{1}E(x^2|y)dy=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{2(1-y^2)^{3/2}}{3\pi}dy=\frac{1}{4}$ (By WolframAlpha).
2. $E(x^2)=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1x^2 f(x,y)rdrd\theta=\frac{1}{\pi}(\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2\theta d\theta)( \int_0^1 r^3dr)=(\frac{1}{\pi})(\pi)(\frac{1}{4})=\frac{1}{4}.$